# Multidimensional array with both String and Integer in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm wondering how to create a multidimensional array that can hold both Integers and Strings.

I'm creating an array to hold playing cards:

deck(0, 0) = 2
deck(0, 1) = Hearts

I'd also like to shuffle the array. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to not use a multidimensional array at all and instead create a specific card class to use with your array.

Comment: Yea there are a couple different possibilities, that being one. Just getting some feedback. Maybe there's an easy way I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the idea of using a class, a class including an array of cards with a new constructor and a shuffle method will tidy things up:

```
Public Class Card
    Public Property Value As Integer = 0
    Public Property Suit As Suits
    Enum Suits
        Hearts = 1
        Clubs = 2
        Spades = 3
        Diamonds = 4
    End Enum
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Value.ToString + "of" + Suit.ToString
    End Function
End Class
Public Class Deck
    Public Shared Cards(51) As Card
    Shared Sub New()
        For I = 1 To 4
            Dim CurrentSuit = CType([Enum].ToObject(GetType(Card.Suits), I), Card.Suits)
            For J = 1 To 13
                Cards((((I - 1) * 13) + J) - 1) = New Card With {.Value = J, .Suit = CurrentSuit}
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub Shuffle()
        Dim rnd As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
        For i = 0 To 51
            Dim tempindex = rnd.Next(0, 52)
            Dim tempcard = Cards(tempindex)
            Cards(tempindex) = Cards(i)
            Cards(i) = tempcard
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

`Dim CurrentDeck As New Deck()` will initialize the deck will all the cards in order.  Calling the `Shuffle` method will shuffle the cards ready for dealing(`CurrentDeck.Shuffle`).

Comment: Wow this is a very elegant solution, the only thing I don't like is the Shuffle subroutine. I think I might adjust that but everything else is REALLY elegantly setup. I like the enum for the suits, the toString override, very nicely done.

Comment: Thank you.  There are probably better shuffle routines, but this has the advantage of simplicity, plus you can increase the amount of shuffling by increasing the the iterations to a higher multiple of 52 and use the modulus 52 of i for the index.

Comment: That is not a good algorithm for shuffling, you would need to do a lot more than 52 switches for most of the cards to be shuffled. You should use the Fisher-Yates algorthm, which only requires 51 swaps and guarantees that all cards are shuffled, and the code for it isn't even more complicated.

Comment: Actually this shuffles every card at least once

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use multidimensional arrays like that, for several reasons:

- If you want to mix data types, the array type would be object, and you need to cast every value when you use them.
- The relation between the values that belong together is just in the code that you write, so you have no help from the compiler to keep you from mixing values from different items.
- The properties for an item is just identified by a number, it would be better to give it a name.

Create a custom class for the items:

```
Public Class Card

  Public Property Value As Integer
  Public Property Suit As String

End Class

Dim deck As New List(Of Card)
```

Or use one that exist:

```
Dim deck As New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String))
```

The `Tuple` class is easy to use as it already exists, however the names of the properties (`Item1` and `Item2`) isn't very descriptive.